# Unicode-aware equivalent of \b in JavaScript regexes

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

There is [a piece of JavaScript code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rivescript) with several regexes using `\b` to match word boundaries. They don't work as expected on Unicode input. They work more or less like this:

```
',.,.Michał /#@$^Øystein(*()'.match(/\b.+?\b/g) // => ["Micha", "ł /#@$^Ø", "ystein"]
```

I would like the expression above to return `[ "Michał", " /#@$^", "Øystein" ]`.

The expressions inside `\b` are actually more complicated than `.+?` and some of them are generated, so changing them is quite tricky. Ideally, I would like to keep these expressions unchanged, and substitute `\b` with something that matches zero-width word boundaries in a Unicode-aware way.

Is it possible at all? If it is, how can I do it? If it is not, how can I do it in a way that requires least changes to the expressions inside `\b`?

I hoped ES6 could help, but it won't – the behaviour of `\b` hasn't been changed there.